# Double select narrow results

Tags: mysql, join

I want to select the views, increase and percentage increase from a table but only show the unique id's. I can get the information what I want but it's more then I need and can't narrow the results.

I have the following data:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| datum      | youtube_id | views | likes |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| 2012-10-07 |     123456 |   100 |   100 |
| 2012-10-07 |      98765 |   200 |   200 |
| 2012-10-08 |     123456 |   150 |   150 |
| 2012-10-08 |      98765 |   300 |   300 |
| 2012-10-09 |     123456 |   300 |   300 |
| 2012-10-09 |      98765 |   500 |   500 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

And the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
id, 
startcount, 
endcount, 
(endcount - startcount)increasing, 
((endcount - startcount) / ( startcount ) *100)percentChange
FROM (SELECT youtube_id AS id, views AS startcount
    FROM charts
    WHERE datum =  '2012-10-08')startRange,
(SELECT views AS endcount
FROM charts
WHERE datum =  '2012-10-09')endRange
```

This gives me the following result:

```
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| id     | startcount | endcount | increasing | percentChange |
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| 123456 |        150 |      300 |        150 |      100.0000 |
|  98765 |        300 |      300 |          0 |        0.0000 |
| 123456 |        150 |      500 |        350 |      233.3333 |
|  98765 |        300 |      500 |        200 |       66.6667 |
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
```

The expected result would be:

```
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| id     | startcount | endcount | increasing | percentChange |
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| 123456 |        150 |      300 |        150 |      100.0000 |
|  98765 |        300 |      500 |        200 |       66.6667 |
+--------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+
```

I have been looking at a group by or a join but can't figure this out, already redoing this for a few days now but running into a loop myself.

If someone can point me to the right direction or help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caaad/1)

```
SELECT 
    c1.youtube_id id, 
    c1.views startcount, 
    c2.views endcount, 
    c2.views - c1.views increasing, 
    (c2.views - c1.views) * 100 / c1.views percentChange
FROM 
    charts c1
    inner join
    charts c2 on c1.youtube_id = c2.youtube_id
WHERE 
    c1.datum = '2012-10-08' and c2.datum =  '2012-10-09'
```

Edit: changed the increasing

Comment: Thanks for the really quick and correct answer. I now understand how the inner join works. Thanks!